# How to stop Vue.js 3 watch() API triggering on exit

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have implemented a `watch` within a Vue component that displays product information. The `watch` watches the `route` object of `vue-router` for a `ProductID` param to change. When it changes, I want to go get the product details from the back-end API.

To watch the `route`, I do this in `Product.vue`:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

    export default {
      setup() {
        const route = useRoute();

        async function getProduct(ProductID) {
          await axios.get(`/api/product/${ProductID}`).then(..do something here)
        }
    
        // fetch the product information when params change
        watch(() => route.params.ProductID, async (newID, oldID) => {
            await getProduct(newId)
          },
          //watch options
          {
          deep: true,
          immediate: true
          }
        )
      },
    }
```

The above code works, except that if a user navigates away from `Product.vue`, for example using the back button to go back to the homepage, the `watch` is triggered again and tries to make a call to the API using `undefined` as the ProductID (becaues `ProductID` param does not exist on the homepage `route`) e.g. `http://localhost:8080/api/product/undefined`. This causes an error to be thrown in the app.

1. Why does the `watch` trigger when a user has navigated away from `Product.vue`?
2. How can this be prevented properly? I can do it using `if(newID) { await getProduct(newId) }` but it seems counterintuitive to what the `watch` should be doing anyway.

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**
Place the following at the top replacing the name for whatever your route is called:

```
if (route.name !== "YourRouteName") {
   return;
}
```

That will ensure nothing happens if you are not on the route you want to watch.

Comment: Try it out without watch options

Comment: The watch options are required or else nothing renders on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Instead of watching the current route, use `vue-router` `onBeforeRouteUpdate`, which only gets called if the route changed and the same component is reused.

From https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#navigation-guards:

```
import { onBeforeRouteLeave, onBeforeRouteUpdate } from 'vue-router'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    // same as beforeRouteLeave option with no access to `this`
    onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from) => {
      const answer = window.confirm(
        'Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!'
      )
      // cancel the navigation and stay on the same page
      if (!answer) return false
    })

    const userData = ref()

    // same as beforeRouteUpdate option with no access to `this`
    onBeforeRouteUpdate(async (to, from) => {
      // only fetch the user if the id changed as maybe only the query or the hash changed
      if (to.params.id !== from.params.id) {
        userData.value = await fetchUser(to.params.id)
      }
    })
  },
}
```

Comment: Came back to this problem in a different component and this solution worked nicely.

Comment: That's a solution, but unfortunately still a half baked solution, since now at the moment you're loading data the `router.currentRoute` doesn't reflect the current parameters, which can lead to confusing bugs (trust me XD). Also, a later `onBeforeRouteUpdate` hook could cancel the transition, leaving you to reload the data although the route doesn't change. What would _actually_ be useful is an `onAfterRouteUpdate` hook, but, alas, that does not appear to exist.

Comment: @ElteHupkes take a look at my update in the question

Comment: @volumeone Yeah I considered that solution... Breaking edge cases: routes without a name, and two different routes rendering the same component. That may or may not be something you worry about, though.

Comment: @ElteHupkes You wanted an "onAfterRouteUpdate" which is kind of possible using `flush: "post"` on a `watchEffect()`. I changed my `onBeforeRouteUpdate` to `watchEffect` and it still works well.

Comment: @volumeone Hmmm yes, I'm currently using an ugly hack with `nextTick`, but that sounds like it might roughly do the same thing and be...slightly less ugly. Although I still think it might fire if you leave the route in that case. The implied benefit of my imaginary `onAfterRouteUpdate` is that you get the guarantee it didn't leave your route.

Answer (score 1):

1. `watch` registers the watcher inside an vue-internal, but component-independent object. I think it's a `Map`. So destroying the component has no effect on the reactivity system.
2. Just ignore the case where `newID` is `undefined`, like you already did. But to prevent wrapping your code in a big `if` block just use `if(newID === undefined)return;` at the beginning of your callback. If your ids are always truthy (`0` and `""` are invalid ids) you can even use `if(!newID)return;`.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere about `watch` not being dependent on a component? Would love to know more about how it works and where in the Vue lifecycle it sits.

Comment: That watcher really only fires once, and no more than once, after the route is left, so I'm pretty sure it's tied to the component. It just hasn't been removed yet the moment that the route changes.

Answer (score 0):

well, in your use case the best approach would be to have a method or function which makes the api call to the server, having watch is not a really good use of it, ***because it will trigger whenever route changes and you do not want that to happen***, what you want is simply get the productID from route and make the api call,
so it can be done with getting the productID in the created or mounted and make the api call!